# how can I override the toString method in openedge?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have a serializable class that I would like to provide my own toString when being serialized to JSON.

````
    DEFINE PUBLIC PROPERTY address1 AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO 
    GET.
    SET.
    
    METHOD PUBLIC OVERRIDE CHARACTER toString(  ):
        
        DEFINE VARIABLE result AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

        RETURN address1 + address2 + city + country.

    END METHOD.

END CLASS. ```

I am also assigning the class to a temptable and using the write-json method of a dataset to output but I get the standard toString representation .."myClass": {
                "prods:objId": 1,
                "myClass": {
                    "address1": "xxxxx"
                }
            } 

can I somehow override the toString being used ?
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JsonSerializer` does not use `ToString()` ,nor does it give you any control over the format that's produced. The [`Serialize` method](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-117/page/Serialize-method-JsonSerializer.html) describes what data is written. If you want this ability added into the ABL, you can add an "Idea" at https://openedge.ideas.aha.io/ideas ; OE product management review these ideas periodically.

If you want control today over what is written, you will need to roll your own. By way of example, OE has the [`IJsonSerializer`](https://github.com/consultingwerk/ADE-Sourcecode/blob/master/src/corelib/OpenEdge/Core/Json/IJsonSerializer.cls) interface, which allows types to declare that they can be serialised using the [`JsonSerializer`](https://github.com/consultingwerk/ADE-Sourcecode/blob/master/src/corelib/OpenEdge/Core/Json/JsonSerializer.cls) class.